# How to list all appRoleAssignments in Microsoft Graph API or Azure AD Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I can see how to query appRoleAssignments for a given user in AAD Graph:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{my-tenant}/users/{user-guid}/appRoleAssignments
```

But I can't find a way to retrieve all appRoleAssignments within the domain. My use case is Power BI (reporting tool) and, while I could fetch all the apps, all the users, and then run a query per user, this would be very expensive given the thousands of users and apps.

Ideally, I'd retrieve all the apps (check), all the users (check) and all the appRoleAssignments to link them (this question).

Tried this:
    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appRoleAssignments

But get back:

> Direct queries to this resource type are not supported.

Tried this:
    https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/appRoleAssignments

But get this:

> Resource not found for the segment 'appRoleAssignments'

Answer (score 2):

The [`appRoleAssignment`](http://appRoleAssignment) resource cannot be queried across the entire tenant. It needs to be scoped to a parent resource, either a [`user`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/users), a [`servicePrincipal`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/serviceprincipal), or a [`group`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/group).

Thinking outside the box, you might be able to compile a collection without as much overhead as you're expected. To do this, you'd need to store it outside the AD and periodically refresh the data set.

If you're generally primarily concerned with the [`user`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users) assignments, you could try using `/delta` queries against `user` resource list. This would let you only retrieve `user` resources that have been changed. Once you have a `user`, you ran retrieve the `appRoleAssignment` resources for them and store them in your external data store.

For the list of potential `appRole` resources that might be assigned to a given user, you can get this by retrieving the list of `application` resources from the tenant and looking at the `appRoles` property (`/beta/applications?$select=appRoles`).

For near-real-time changes, you can use the `/beta/users/delta` and then periodically poll both `user` and `application` collections to fully refresh the larger data set.

Keep in mind that this isn't something I've attempted to POC so there may be issues I'm not considering. It is entirely within the `/beta` endpoint which means API behavior and data sets could change at any time and without warning. *That said*, it's a very interesting thought exorcise. I'd be curious to hear where you end up with this.

---

Just to clarify for anyone who might surface this in a search, Azure AD Graph and Microsoft Graph are two separate APIs and user different permission scopes and syntax. In general, developers should be using Microsoft Graph wherever possible as it will eventually supplant the older Azure AD Graph.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I can see the Azure AD graph has a column for appRoles but I don't seem to be able to get it to return any data in that column. I tried adding "?$expand=appRoles" to the query URL but it's still returning an empty list

Comment: Aha! Looks like you were heading in the right direction with $select approach. I couldn't get this to return any data on the user table but am able to retrieve the appRoleAssignments on /users with "https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments" (note that this is on the older azure graph and there doesn't appear to be a comparable option on the newer Microsoft Graph API).
So this is as good an answer as I can get right now - thanks!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is the difference between a `servicePrincipal` and an `application`. For multi-tenant apps that the tenant doesn't own the registration (Graph Explorer for example), these surface in `servicePrincipal`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to upvote or mark an answer is I'm deemed too lowly of reputation to do so.
Anyways, big thanks to [Marc Lafleur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur-microsoft) who sent me in the right direction.
There seems to be no way to retrieve the app/users list separately, but expanding the appRoleAssignments on the /users call to the Azure Graph API does the trick. Note that there seems no comparable way to do this with the newer Microsoft Graph API :(

This was the call that started the magic working for me:

```
https://graph.windows.net/my-tenant/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments
```

Comment: The same call should also work in /beta in Microsoft Graph, except for the fact that it has a bug in it.  You should also be aware that $expand operations in AAD Graph are limited to returning only 20 items in the expansion due to performance limitations.  If a user has more than 20 apps assigned, you'll miss some of them. The same is true for directory operations in Microsoft Graph, since it essentially sits on top of AAD Graph.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ... (Classic Graph)

```
 https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id-AsGuid-NoBraces}/users/{UserId-AsGuid-NoBraces}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

The response will be in the users context - so the user will be the principalID .

The application Id will be in the resourceID - This is NOT the application id.  This is the objectId that the app registration points to.

*(Comments about your situation)*
Your general dilemma about trying to get the "all list" by querying across all users seems like a real problem at first.  I avoided this by using a known list. The reason I chose to use a known list is that there are many other applications in our environment that my app has no knowledge or operational authority to list or manipulate via code.  I only work against a known target list of app registrations and their underlying object id.  So this is how I avoid your general dilemma.

The Azure Portal (in my case) shows me the underlying id's I need to know about to add to my app specific registrations list.

It is possible this API will work for you - I chose not to use it - but I can't remember why.

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id-AsGuid-NoBraces}/servicePrincipals/{AppOBJECTID-AsGuid-NoBraces}/appRolesAssignedTo?api-version=1.6
```

.

Comment: Thanks for that, but it doesn't really help me, I'm afraid. We user PowerBI to show internal and external users who has access to which applications (and there are thousands of each).
That same query format does work for me (as I said above), but doesn't fit the use-case I posited so the question is still "Is it possible to return all appRoleAssignments in a single request?").
If the answer is no, then so be it!

Comment: There are other ways besides Graph to get at the guts of an AD store.  Also the beta endpoint of the "new" Graph is starting to support the objects so you may not be out of luck much longer.   That is what your "direct queries" error is all about  - they stop you in the New Graph from pulling out non-directly supported types - even though you clearly just accessed the object via your call.